# How to decrease the size of the image in the card reveal of CSS

Tags: html, css, material-design

On tapping the image, the info reveals itself as shown on [this page](https://materializecss.com/cards.html#reveal).

But in my case, the image is quite large, so how do I decrease the size of the image to keep the box small without cropping the image? Or even if cropping occurs also, how to do it?

```html
<div class="card" style="overflow: visible;">
  <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
    <img class="activator" src="https://dummyimage.com/1024x800/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="card-content">
    <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="card-reveal" style="display: none; transform: translateY(0%);">
    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
    <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try putting css for image width:100%

Comment: can you make a fiddle on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: .card-image default is `width:100%` in materialzecss, I think you missed some key point CSS, you can create an online example let us know how to help you.

Answer (score 0):

For your `div` having `class="card"` set the width manually to whatever value you want. Without setting the width, it will be `100%` of the parent by default.

Also, you must have to include 3 resources in your `html` for all the functions of `materialize.css` to work properly:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Look at the demonstration below:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="card" style="overflow: visible; width: 30%; margin: 10px auto;">
  <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
    <img class="activator" src="https://dummyimage.com/1024x800/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="card-content">
    <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="card-reveal" style="display: none; transform: translateY(0%);">
    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
    <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kavc89nh/17/